# How to make a deepcopy of a dataframe with dataframes within it? (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-copy

I want a copy of a dataframe which contains a dataframe. When I change something in the nested dataframe, it shouldn't change in the original dataframe.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   0  1                                                  2
0  1  2  <__main__.PossibleCombinations object at 0x000...
1  4  5                                                  6
```

Generated with the next code:

```
import copy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

class PossibleCombinations:
    def __init__(self, dfCombinations, numberCombinations):
        self.dfCombinations = dfCombinations
        self.numberCombinations = numberCombinations

df.iloc[0,2] = PossibleCombinations(pd.DataFrame(data= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]),6)
print(df)
```

When I make a deepcopy of the hole dataframe and the nested dataframe and change something in the 
nested dataframe in the copy, the value also changes in the original.

```
deepCopy = copy.deepcopy(df)
deepCopy.iloc[0,2].dfCombinations = copy.deepcopy(df.iloc[0,2].dfCombinations)

deepCopy.iloc[0,2].dfCombinations.iloc[0,2] = "doei"

print(deepCopy.iloc[0,2].dfCombinations)
print(" ")
print(df.iloc[0,2].dfCombinations)
```

output:

```
   0  1     2
0  1  2  doei
1  4  5     6

   0  1     2
0  1  2  doei
1  4  5     6
```

but I want:

```
   0  1     2
0  1  2  doei
1  4  5     6

   0  1     2
0  1  2     3
1  4  5     6
```

**What is the fix for this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fix:

```
import pickle
deepCopy = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(df))

deepCopy.iloc[0,2].dfCombinations.iloc[0,2] = "doei"

print(deepCopy.iloc[0,2].dfCombinations)
print(" ")
print(df.iloc[0,2].dfCombinations)
```

output:

```
3
   0  1     2
0  1  2  doei
1  4  5     6

   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

This solves the problem!